# Clarification about Java 8 compiler enhancement in inheritance and constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am studying Java and in the book it is written "Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor super() if the first statement is not a call to the parent constructor."

But for me it is incomplete, the complete would be "Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor super() if the first statement is not a call to the parent constructor, or a call to this()" this() meaning any constructor in the class with or without parameters, am I right?

What I mean is that in case 1 the compiler will indeed add super() as first statement, but in case 2 it doesn't for the constructor with argument:

Case 1 :

```
public class MyClass{ 
    public MyClass() {}
}
```

After compilation, becomes :

```
public class MyClass { 
    public MyClass() {super();}
}
```

Case 2:

```
public class MyClass{ 
    public MyClass() {}
    public MyClass(int num) { this(); }
}
```

After compilation, becomes :

```
public class MyClass{ 
    public MyClass() {super();}
    public MyClass(int num) { this(); }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're quite right, a call to another constructor of the same class such as `this()` is also perfectly valid. You can see the bytecode emitted by the Java compiler using the `javap` tool:

```
$ javap -c ../MyClass.class
Compiled from "MyClass.java"
public class MyClass {
  public MyClass();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public MyClass(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #2                  // Method "<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

The `MyClass(int)` constructor delegates to `MyClass()`, which in turn calls the default `Object()` constructor.

Comment: thanx for this clarification and for the javap tool I didn't know it.